# Child component not called

Tags: angular, nativescript

Both Child and Parent are below in same typescript file.
The child is not getting rendered. The alert in child's constructor is also not getting triggered. However when the template is put back into parent's everything works fine.

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { SetupItemViewArgs } from "nativescript-angular/directives";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router/router-extensions';
import { FirebaseService, BackendService } from "../services";


//CHILD
@Component({
  selector: 'roomrow',
  template: `
      <CardView class="studentCard" margin="2" elevation="10" radius="1">
          <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto" columns="auto, auto, *">
              <Label [text]="item.id" textWrap="true" stretch="aspectFill" colSpan="3" row="0"></Label>
              <Label [text]="item.name" textWrap="true" row="2" colSpan="1"></Label>
          </GridLayout>
      </CardView>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
class RoomrowComponent {
  @Input() item: any;
  constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
  ) {
    alert(this.item);//not called
  }
}

//PARENT
@Component({
  selector: 'rooms',
   template: `
    <StackLayout>
      <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
          <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of (rooms$ | async)">
            <roomrow [item]="item"></roomrow>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
     </ScrollView>
  </StackLayout>
   `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class RoomsComponent {
  public rooms$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rooms$ = <any>this.firebaseService.getPath('users/' + BackendService.token + '/rooms');
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's missing declarations in parent's module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    roomsRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    RoomrowComponent,//<== Needed
    RoomsComponent
  ]
})
export class RoomsModule { }
```

and need to change `class RoomrowComponent` to `export class RoomrowComponent`